# Can I apply for work visa for one country and tourist visa for another at the same time?

Tags: visas, schengen, australia, tourist-visas, uk-residents

Some background to my question:

- I'm on a work visa in UK
- My husband is on a different category of work visa in UK
- I applied to switch my visa (within UK) to be his dependant and it takes another 6-7 weeks for a decision. BUT they scanned my passport and gave the original back to me and said I need not turn it in

My questions are:

- Since I have my passport with me, can I apply for a tourist visa now- Schengen or Australian? (I will only travel after my visa switch is approved)
- Will my tourist visa be invalidated after my residence status is changed?

Answer (score 3):

> My question now is, since I have my passport with me, can I apply for a tourist visa now- Schengen or Australian? (I will only travel after my visa switch is approved)

Yes.

> Will my tourist visa be invalidated after my residence status is changed?

No.